# Group by value extracted from function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to group by a value extracted from a function. `[fnSplitter]` extracts the second delimiter from "123-456-459-905". In other words, it extracts "456". I alias the second delimiter as `[Col_B]` and I would like to group by it. Is this possible?

```
select
    (
        select data
        from [fnSpliter] (REPLACE ((REPLACE (pk, '-', '|')),'||', '|-'), '|')
        where id = 2
    ) as [Col_B]
from [Table]
group by [Col_B]
```

Comment: show sample data and our put now with expected output

Comment: Your T-SQL isn't even valid, to call a function you must always schema prefix it.

Comment: To use this at all, it's probably best to use `OUTER APPLY`. Makes it easier to read to start with.

Comment: `I would like to group by it` grouping by a column returned from a TVF is not different to a column returned from a `TABLE`/`VIEW`. You could even reference columns returns from all 3 different object types and a `VALUES` clause in the `GROUP BY` if you had such a query `GROUP BY Tbl.Col, Vw.Col, tvf.Col, V.Col;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't group by an alias.  So se `apply`:

```
select f.data as col_b
from [Table] t cross apply
     [fnSpliter](REPLACE(REPLACE(pk, '-', '|'), '||', '|-'), '|') f
where f.id = 2
group by f.data
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a scalar function, as your question suggests, you could `select` the values in a subquery, than `group by` in the outer query:

```
select [Col_B]
from (
    select dbo.[fnSpliter](REPLACE ((REPLACE (pk, '-', '|')),'||', '|-'), '|') as [Col_B]
    from [Table]
    where id = 2
) t
group by [Col_B]
```

Note that the name of the function should be prefixed with the schema it belongs to - I assumed `dbo`.

The example hardly makes sense. In a real query, you would likely use an aggregate function in the outer query (such as `COUNT(*)` for example).